# How To Post To Back end Server

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the following angular code to post a string to my backend server. I am getting the response error.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  apiURL = environment.apiUrl;
  stockUrl = this.apiURL + '/api/stock';

  postStock(stocks) {
    this.http.post(this.stockUrl, stocks, {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", res);
      },
      response => {
        console.log("POST call in error", response);
      })
  } 
}
```

I am getting the console log "POST call in error Unknown Error"

This is the component code:

```
stockdata: Cagr[];
stock: String;

constructor(private api: ApiService){}

post(stock){
  this.api.postStock(stock);
  console.log("this is the stock I posted", stock);
}
```

The console log does post the accurate stock I ngmodel it in the html file.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Did you initialazi the HttpClient in the constructor of ApiService??

Comment: @LeanPilar yes I did define the HttpClient in the Constructor for the Api service

Comment: The code you show should work, one more possible is that the enviroment.apiURL does not start with http. Did you try postman or others to test your post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seems the service hit is not reaching to server side
2. Verify the post submission in Post man collection
3. Then ensure you have proxy pass (or) the serviceURL is reaching your server side  stockUrl = this.apiURL + '/api/stock';. Your server side ensure its having CORS allowed.

Ref:  [Angular 4: Unknown error after POST request to REST api on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626348/angular-4-unknown-error-after-post-request-to-rest-api-on-localhost)

Comment: All of your comments are on track with the errors I am getting in chrome dev window and netcore. I get a null error in netcore. The stock is not making it to the back end. I do console log it from the front end.

I used postman with this body "{"UserName":"johndoe"}" and get the 500 internal error to the back server url.   Does the body sound right?

Comment: which stock api service you are calling ? is it open source / custom built ?

Comment: The issue is the back end. Using Postman I get the same 500 internal error. Chrome dev console windows says CORS is the issue, but I have cors enabled for all on the server.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer and work getting why CORS is not working on the server side